# Can’t get my MBP running since macOS Mojave

Tags: macos, mojave

Since I updated my MBP, it doesn’t work anymore. Had trouble installing, then it was slow, and now I can’t do anything anymore other then going into Recovery mode. When running Disk Ultility, it always tell me while running First Aid, that there is an error: cib: o_oid(0x0)
File system check exit code is 0.
I don’t know what to do anymore.

Comment: tell us about your MBP. try starting in safe mode...Hold Shift key during start up. read this https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262

Answer (score 2):

Lets try to repair your disk in Single User mode.

Hold Shift key during start up.

Let it finish ..

then enter

```
/sbin/fsck -fy
```

When it’s done, you’ll see a message saying “** The volume [name] appears to be OK” if everything is fine.

If it found problems, you’ll see a “***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****” message. This indicates the fsck command found and fixed problems. The fsck command may find additional errors after repairing the first batch of errors, so **Apple recommends you run the fsck command again** if it found and fixed problems. **Run the above fsck command over and over** until you see a “** The volume [name] appears to be OK” message.

When the fsck command says your disk is okay, type the following command at the terminal and press Enter:

```
reboot
```